# Passing boolean value to a .net function from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I need to call the method `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` to extract a zip file in PowerShell. When I try to call it using: `[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($source, $destinationPath, $True)`

I get an error saying `Cannot convert argument "entryNameEncoding", with value: "True", for "ExtractToDirectory" to type "System.Text.Encoding": "Cannot convert value "True" to type "System.Text.Encoding". Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.Boolean' to 'System.Text.Encoding'.""`

I have also tried to create a new boolean variable using `[Boolean]$b = $true;` and then pass this but it still gives the same error. How can I pass the `true` value to overwrite the files if present in the destination?

`Note:` I can't use the `Expand-Archive` cmdlet as it's only supported from PS V5.0. I need my scripts to run with PS4.1

I could also delete the folder if it exists and then extract, but would like to use the existing.

Comment: I am sorry I don't have much experience in .Net, But when I check in the internet bool is a short form for ``System.Boolean`` and I am passing the value ``$True`` which is a PS value for true, I have also tried creating a ``System.Boolean`` variable and pass this. But no luck.

Comment: [It has](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=netcore-3.1), - in .Net Core version, though. A system with PSh 4.0 unlikely has .Net core.

Comment: The `overwriteFiles` option is supported only in .NET Core, which would require Powershell Core (which is 7 and upwards, in which case you might as well use `Expand-Archive`). In other words, you can't tell the class to overwrite files, you'll have to the delete and/or merge yourself.